# Laravel 4.2 Incorrect Datetime format while using database queue

Tags: laravel

I have develop new application in laravel 4.2. I update davelip package via composer. I set up all thing as per github instruction. But some how get error like:

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2
015-09-25T18:56:51+0000' for column 'timestamp' at row 1 (SQL: update queues set status = 1, retries = 1, timestamp = 2015-09-25T18:56:51+0000
, updated_at = 2015-09-25 18:56:51 where id = 14)

I created queue table from PHP artisan migrates command but when ever I used a queue for bulk mail sending I got the same error in queue:listen command.

I need full help regarding this Issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found that the version of devlip database queue package have bug. So I update previous version of it. And Stable version is "davelip/laravel-database-queue": "0.4.0".